# Electric Meter jumpers

Tags: meter

I had an electrician come out to install a sub-meter. The city has not sent me a meter box, not sure why this was done out of order, so the electrician could not actually finish the line. This meter only runs a NEMA 14-50.

Can I install jumpers to complete the circuit until I actually receive the meter? What type of jumpers would I need. I'll be pulling ~15amps off this line when in use.

[image]

Comment: The linked item is overpriced, check with your local Electrical Supply House, but here's is what you need: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B006GEEJZQ/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_AqW2ybKFJ7EMN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is an EV submeter. My guess is that adding a jumper is the equivalent of bypassing the meter, which means you'd be stealing power from the utility. I don't think they'd take too kindly to that.

However, if this meter is fed from your primary meter (which is possible, and what I have, albeit in a very different setup) then you could jump it by taking the wires and splicing them with a screw-down terminal, the same as the neutral (white wires) has been done.

It would simply be as if you didn't have a submeter. It helps that the wires are color coded nicely too. Red to red, black to black, leave the green as is...

Comment: Yeah this is wired to my main meter. It tracks usage separately to save money off our power bill. Is connecting these wires easier than connecting the plugs together with something similar to meter bypass bar? Can't seem to find these bypasses easily maybe there's a substitute to use?

Comment: Well, it really depends on how janky you want things to get... @Tyson linked one option. Theoretically, any copper bar with the same cross-sectional area as the wires will do, which means ~13.2mm^2. For example, a 1/2x1/16" bar will do.